Movie about monsters living underground who come up to the human world to steal food
There's this movie I remember from my childhood about a city of monsters living underground. The monsters went up to the human city/world through a hole at night to steal food from the people's houses and there was a teenage monster  who meets a teenage human and they become friends. 
There's a scene I remember when the monsters took baths filled with mud and the monster's mom had 3 boobs (weird I know).

You might be thinking of the movie Little Monsters (1989). In this movie, there are monsters that live in another dimension that come out at night from under the beds of kids. The monsters are actually kids themselves, which went into the world, and got trapped there.
The main character, Brian (Fred Savage) catches one of these monsters one night, and they eventually become friends. They play several pranks on other kids. One of these pranks involves replacing several of the ingredients of a kid's lunch with gross things.
I don't recall there being a monster with three breasts, but you could be confusing that with the movie Total Recall, where one of the Martian women has three which is caused by radiation.
Here is a synopsis from IMDB.

A child meets the monster that lives under his bed. He even becomes one of his best friends. Soon the child discovers a whole new world of fun and games under his bed where pulling pranks on kids and other monsters is the main attraction.

